# Codename One - AutoCompleteTF bad behavior

Tags: android, user-interface, codenameone

Another day, another bug...
I have three AutoCompleteTextFields with the filter overrided to get completion from my REST service, but my big problem is that the suggestions popups of those text are clickthrough... so when I've already completed one of them, any click on the suggestion popup of another will trigger the underlying ACTF, which is already filled and so show it's own popup, making impossible to select the item from the other ACTF suggestion popup.

The two screenshots here show the situation, the ACTF are the textfield hinted "Partenaire", "Contact..." and the already autocompleted one under.

On the second screenshot, I've tried to select the item over the third ACTF, and so the four first results are from the third ACTF, and the four last are from the "Partenaire" ACTF.

Is there a way to override something like onShow() for the popup and it's hiding  equivalent, so I could disable the other ACTF when I type in one of them ?

I think it's a good way to solve the problem, but I am open to any other idea :)

I've forget to mention it, but the problem occur on Android and on the simulator, but iOS has not such problem.

[image][image]

Comment: Does this happen only on device (android), or does it happen also for you in the simulator?

Comment: It happen on device and on simulator

Comment: But only on Android, never on iOS

Comment: I can't seem to reproduce the problem.  [This is my test case](https://gist.github.com/shannah/44e3a91938542b58e5a6cfa43799f95c).  See if this test case exhibits the problem for you.  If not, can you modify it to reproduce the problem?

Comment: I can't reproduce it with your test case, but I've noticed that the bug always occur when the suggestion box is North of it's source ACTF, and I don't know why it's located North instead of South, so I can't reproduce it too on the test case...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check that your UI has scrolling set correctly, only one container in the hierarchy can be scrollable on the Y axis. By default the Form's content pane should be scrollable on Y (unless it's a border layout).

Comment: So the problem is that the ACTF suggestion boxes are scrollable ? My form is scrollable too, so there are more than one scrollable container on screen and it cause the bad behavior ? Is there any way to change the scrollable behavior of the suggestion boxes (without rewriting the whole ACTF class) ?

Comment: You need to have one scrollable container otherwise when you edit and a virtual keyboard pops up we don't know where/what to scroll to the right location. This will apply for any input and is an important usability best practice. Nesting scrollable containers is especially problematic as we don't have scrollbars and with touch scrolling we can't know which component was scrolled.